# Python: Cannot get imports to work when installed on remote server

Tags: python, ubuntu

(Before responding with a 'see this link' answer, know that I've been searching for hours and have probably read it all. I've done my due diligence, I just can't seem to find the solution)

That said, I'll start with my general setup and give details after.

**Setup**: On my desktop, I have a project that I am running in Pycharm, Python3.4, using a virtual environment. In the cloud (AWS). I have an EC2 instance running Ubuntu. I'm not using a virtual environment in the cloud. The cloud machine has both python 2.7 and python 3.5 installed.

[Edit] I've switched to a virtual machine on my cloud environment, and installing from setup distrubution (still broken)

**Problem**: On my desktop, both within pycharm and from the command line (within the virtual environment using workon (project), I can run a particular file called "do_daily.py" without any issues. However, If I try to run the same file on the cloud server, I get the famous import error. 
[edit] Running directly from command line on remote server.

```
python3 src/do_daily.py      

File "src/do_daily.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src.db_backup import dev0_backup as dev0bk
ImportError: No module named 'src.db_backup'
```

**Folder Structure**: My folder structure for the specific import is (among other stuff).

```
+ project
   + src
     - __init__.py
     - do_daily.py
     + db_backup
       - __init__.py
       - dev0_backup.py
```

**Python Path:** (echo $PYTHONPATH)

> /home/ubuntu/automation/Project/src/tg_servers:/home/ubuntu/automation/Project/src/db_backup:/home/ubuntu/automation/Project/src/aws:/home/ubuntu/automation/Project/src:/home/ubuntu/automation/Project

**Other stuff**:

```
print(sys.executable) = /usr/bin/python3
print(sys.path) = gives me all the above plus a bunch of default paths.
```

I have run out of ideas and would appreciate any help.

Thank you, 
SteveJ

**SOLUTION**
Clearly the accepted answer was the most comprehensive and represents the best approach to the problem. However, for those seeing this later - I was able to solve my specific problem a little more directly.

(From within the virtual environment), both the add2virtualenv and creating .pth files did work. What I was missing is that I had to add all packages; src, db_backup, pkgx,y,z etc...

Comment: You run this from cron? .. then that will explain everything.

Comment: nope, at least not yet - right now just running from command line. I'll edit the question to make that clear, thanks.

Comment: Do you pip install your packages or is this just a git clone or copy to a directory? Then I mean your code and not the requirements.

Comment: ``python3 -m src.do_daily`` maybe.. or your pythonpath will be inside ``src``. Then ``src`` will be in the pythonpath as the current working dir is added by python command when it runs.

Comment: @Grimmy; I have a setup.py in the project that I used to create the tar, then I ssh'd the tar to the remote, then extract. I tried python3 setup.py install, but that doesn't seem to have the effect I hoped for (nothing seems to install) so right now I'm just trying to make something run. I may have to manually install external dependencies, but I can't even get that far yet.

Comment: See my comment about pythonpath. That is your problem.

Comment: if you have a setup.py file then you should install your package with `pip install -e .` (notice the last dot) from the directory containing the setup.py file. This puts the package on the Python path. If you're going to run scripts from the command line (as opposed to importing in python code), you should use the `entry_points` parameter in your setup.py - it installs the scripts so you can run them directly  from the command line (no `python -m ...`). Docs: http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point

Comment: @thebjorn - re started the whole thing, switched to virtual env, ran the pip install as you suggest within the virtualenv (workon), still same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a github repository (https://github.com/thebjorn/pyimport.git), and tested the code on a freshly created AWS/Ubuntu instance.

First the installs and updates I did (installing and updating pip3):

```
ubuntu@:~$ sudo apt-get update
ubuntu@:~$ sudo apt install python3-pip
ubuntu@:~$ pip3 install -U pip
```

Then get the code:

```
ubuntu@:~$ git clone https://github.com/thebjorn/pyimport.git
```

My version of `do_daily.py` imports `dev0_backup`, contains a function that tells us it was called, and a `__main__` section (for calling with `-m` or filename):

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-112:~$ cat pyimport/src/do_daily.py
from __future__ import print_function

from src.db_backup import dev0_backup as dev0bk

def do_daily_fn():
    print("do_daily_fn called")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_daily_fn()
```

The `setup.py` file points directly to the `do_daily_fn`:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-112:~$ cat pyimport/setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='pyimport',
    version='0.1',
    description='pyimport',
    url='https://github.com/thebjorn/pyimport.git',
    author='thebjorn',
    license='MIT',
    packages=['src'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': """
            do_daily = src.do_daily:do_daily_fn
        """
    },
    zip_safe=False
)
```

Install the code in dev mode:

```
ubuntu@:~$ pip3 install -e pyimport
```

I can now call do_daily in a number of ways (notice that I haven't done anything with my `PYTHONPATH`).

The console_scripts in setup.py makes it possible too call `do_daily` by just typing its name:

```
ubuntu@:~$ do_daily
do_daily_fn called
```

Installing the package (in dev mode or otherwise) makes the `-m` flag work out-of-the box:

```
ubuntu@:~$ python3 -m src.do_daily
do_daily_fn called
```

You can even call the file directly (although this is by far the ugliest way and I would recommend against it):

```
ubuntu@:~$ python3 pyimport/src/do_daily.py
do_daily_fn called
```

Comment: Wow, that is really above and beyond ... I'll look it over carefully. Thank you.

Comment: I prefer to think of it as expert level procrastination, but you're welcome ;-)

Comment: I sort of feel like I owe you a beer, lunch, something. Ever in SoCal?

Comment: If I may follow up, in this particular case, would you recommend a virtual env on my AWS server or just go direct. People seem religious about their virtual environments but it seems that it will complicate the automated deployment process considerably.

Comment: The main reason why we use virtualenv, both for development and deployment, is dependency management. We have a large code-base compared to the number of developers, and we need to be able to move independently of the versions the OS needs -- there's nothing more fun than breaking the OS when you upgrade a module.. Virtualenvs do add complexity, but once you've started using them it's hard to imagine going back...

Answer (score 0):

Your `PYTHONPATH` should contain `/home/ubuntu/automation/Project` and likely *nothing below it*.

There all reasons to use a virtualenv in production and never install any packages into system Python explicitly. System Python is for running the OS-provided software written in Python. Don't mix it with your deployments.

Comment: 1) Only having the single line doesn't help. 2) How does a virtual environment make my imports work better?

Comment: I fired up a new cloud instance, did everything using virtual environments this time, didn't seem to help the problem.

Comment: I wanted to thank you nonetheless for you assistance in the matter. It turned out that the opposite turned out to be true for me - though I did end up going with a virtual environment, it was only when I included all of my packages in the add2virtualenv statement did things work. I could also accomplish the same by creating a .pth file with all of my packages. Given your reputation, there is no doubt that you know what you are doing - so I struggle to reason why it worked differently for me.

Comment: @SteveJ: Thank you! With all my experience, I sometimes get puzzled by import errors and paths issues, too. Re virtualenvs: while they don't make your imports work any "better", they allow you to experiment without `sudo` and a chance to break your system Python. I've recently seen a machine that had its OS to be re-installed because the system Python packages were broken beyond repair by an ill-considered `sudo pip install`, with several important Python tools failing to work as a result.

Answer (score 0):

A few questions here.

From which directory are you running you program?

Did you try to import the `db_backup` module inside of `src/__init__.py`?

Comment: 1) I'm running from the project directory, above src, 2) import it there as well as in do_daily, or just in __init__.py?

Comment: just write `import db_backup` in your `src/__init__.py`